# How do I setup dual boot for two existing installations?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, windows-xp

My Linux Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is working well on a RAID array that uses HDDs.

I've added an old SSD to the system and see that it has WinXP installed.

There's one piece of legacy software that I would like to resurrect on that SSD.

In this situation, what's the best way to setup dual boot with these existing installations?

Comment: You have two options - use a VM, or add the SSD to your bootloader (e.g: Grub)

Comment: What bootloader are you using? Grub?

Answer (score 0):

> In this situation, what's the best way to invoke a dual boot system?

**There is no way.**

Dual booting is having two OSes installed for the purpose with at least one bootloader manager being loaded before any of those from where users can choose which one to boot.

To make matters worse you already have a (soft)RAID in Linux (Ubuntu). Even if you managed to add the old SSD to the already existing RAID, nothing in that drive would be preserved.

Comment: This is not what I am trying to achieve. See comment above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a VHD from the SSD. Make a backup copy.
2. Since your RAID is handled by the OS, you should be able to add a new hard drive to it. Add the SSD. Maybe. *speculation*
3. Install  [VMbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and configure a new VM. Use your newly created VHD as the harddrive of the VM.
   Now you have xp inside your linux.

If you're feeling like a hotshot you could just connect your SSD, enter your BIOS settings and select to boot first from the SSD. That'll load it. But the other way is sexier, no?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Use a VM - not dual boot, but you would be able to re-purpose the SSD, or
2. Add the SSD's information to your bootloader (e.g: Grub)

---

Presuming you really want dual boot (rather than just access to the software in a VM), then you will need to add the SSD's information to your bootloader (I presume you're using Grub).

As it's Windows XP, you'll need to use something like the following in your configuration, where `hd0,0` is the disk and partition with Windows XP installed on. See `/boot/grub/menu.lst`.

```
title Windows XP
rootnoverify (hd0,0)
chainloader (hd0,0) +1
```

You may also need to use `map` to swap the hard disk ordering:

```
title Windows XP
map (hd0) (hd1)
map (hd1) (hd0)
rootnoverify (hd1,0)
chainloader (hd1,0) +1
```

Comment: To recap: the SSD contains a separate O/S, and I have no intention of adding that device to the RAID array. A quick check reveals that I do have an active /boot/grub directory, but it does not hold a file named menu.lst.

Comment: The system is using Grub and I am now reading the results of bootinfoscript, to investigate the current boot process.